# OpenCV - new Python Bindings and ImageROI?

Tags: python, opencv

How can I set the ROI on a numpy Array, since the new Python-Bindings (cv2) don't support ImageROI (or maybe I didn't use it right)? I don't want to convert between IPLImage and numpy.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can still use the old Python bindings (`import cv`).

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by copying parts from the array to a new numpy array. This new numpy-array could be used with every new binding using numpy. :)

```
a = arr[y:y + size[1], x:x + size[0]]  
tmp = np.array( a, dtype = arr.dtype )
return tmp
```

arr is the numpy-array-image, size is a tuple, x and y are coordinates.

Comment: actually, **a** still hold the values of **arr** (**a** points to the same address as **arr**) which means changing the value of a is actually changing the value of **arr**. thus, the effect is the same as setting ROI of **arr**